# The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first

I customized `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` classes. The code is below:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
{
}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>
{

}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRole() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(l => l.Id).ToTable("tbl_Users", "membership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasKey(l => l.Id).ToTable("tbl_Roles", "membership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().HasKey(l => l.Id).ToTable("tbl_UserClaims", "membership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.UserId, l.ProviderKey, l.LoginProvider }).ToTable("tbl_UserLogins", "membership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(l => new { l.RoleId, l.UserId }).ToTable("tbl_UserRoles", "membership");
    }
```

When I run it first, everything works, creating tables in SQL Server; but If I add property (example `public string FirstName {get; set;}`) in class `ApplicationUser` and run it to make changes in database, throws error:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

I know that I must enable migrations, but is there any way to do it without migrations, because it create own folder(Configuration) and generate class in it?

Answer (score -3):

Just register this entry at the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //Other calls...
  Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
}
```

This will recreate your Identity Database every time that Its model changes. The Context from Identity uses the same concept as any database you create using EF.

You can use other methods, just check here for more information and exemples: [System.Data.Entity Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity(v=vs.113).aspx)

**EDIT:**

To seed you database everytime It's drops you should implement a `Initializer Class` like this one, and override the `Seed` method to put some "fake" data:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("admim"))
        {
            var roleresult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(Administrador));
        }

        //Create User=Admin with password=123456
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.UserName = "sysadmin";
        var adminresult = UserManager.Create(user, "123456");

        //Add User Admin to Role Admin
        if (adminresult.Succeeded)
        {
            var result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
        }
    }
 }
```

Then register this in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //Other calls...
  Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
}
```

Comment: I did it, but now  throws this error. Cannot drop database "TestSecurity" because it is currently in use.

Comment: @www1986 Probly you are acessing this DataBase from Management Studio or from Visual Studio Server Explorer. Make sure that theres no connections opened to this DataBase or will be impossible to drop something thats Its in use. Close Any app that you are using to query this DataBase. If did't work, just pause and restart the SQL Server Instance, this will close any left connection.

Comment: How can you possibly suggest `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` as a fix for this problem? Do you realize that there's a high change of somebody reading your answer and putting it in production code?

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu my Answers fits the question, read everything before do this: "[but is there any way to do it without migrations]"

Comment: @Fals yes it works. but now I have another problem, as you write above Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>()) this drops database and than creates and all old informations are lost. how to do it without losing old records?

Comment: @www1986 I Updated my Answers, see above!